# Signing up for Ubuntu One--it says "Please verify your email."

Tags: ubuntu-one, email

What does "Please verify your email." mean?  I double checked and i entered my email address, spelled correctly, formatted correctly, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I think it means you need to go check that email address and click a link in the email you just got from Ubuntu One.